# firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-8000C-25/26.ucode (-2)

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, debian, wifi, linux-device-driver

Hello I have a `Lenovo T460` and just installed `Debian 8.7.1` but my `wifi` doesnt work. I'd read that I need `kernel 4.1+` to have working the `wifi` and just updated to `4.9.0` but when I restart the computer with that kernel I'm getting two errors

```
iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-8000C-26.ucode (-2)
iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-8000C-25.ucode (-2)
```

I had other more errors but I've been clearing but those last I can't find a way to fix. Does anyone know what can I do?

thank you in advance for any help

Comment: I think you need to run `sudo apt-get install firmware-iwlwifi`.

Comment: @IanAbbott, it doesn't work for me (allready the newest version).

Answer (score 2):

In my case this was happening after Linux was suspended and then woke up. What helped (except for a reboot, of course) was removing the kernel modules, reinserting them and restarting the network (Fedora):

`rmmod iwlmvm
rmmod iwlwifi
modprobe iwlmvm
modprobe iwlwifi
/etc/init.d/network restart`

Comment: On Debian 4.9, I had to replace **/etc/init.d/network** by **/etc/init.d/networking**. 
Furthermore, this answer doesn't work for me.

Comment: This post helped me with the same issue (after suspend) on Fedora 25 with kernel 4.9.45-21 with the Centrino Advanced-N 6205 (rev 34) nic. I used `rmmod iwldvm iwlwifi` followed by `modprobe iwldvm iwlwifi`

Answer (score 0):

From logs it seems that your *iwlwifi* driver is not able to find appropriate version of ucode file to load.
Simple reason behind this could be that, you've updated your kernel to 4.1, which indirectly updated *iwlwifi* driver but in root file system you still have old firmware files because of which driver is failing to find finrware files and failing to load.

Look into **/etc/firmware**, does it have mentioned firmware files (i.e. iwlwifi-8000C-26.ucode etc.)

If not download appropriate files from [iwlwifi ucode files](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi) and place it in appropriate location.

Comment: I think only Android uses **/etc/firmware**, unless I'm mistaken. Regular Linux distros use **/lib/firmware** (Debian certainly does).

Comment: I guess your are right, I had Android device in front of me and took that as reference.
Need to look into linux based machine.

Comment: On the link, I can find only the 8000C-13 and 8000C-16..

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I managed to resolve it like this :
(tested on debian 9.1)

```
cd /tmp
git clone https://github.com/OpenELEC/iwlwifi-firmware.git
cp iwlwifi-firmware/firmware/*.ucode /lib/firmware
modprobe -r iwlwifi
modprobe iwlwifi
```

Check `dmesg` command, there should be something present like

```
[24227.637924] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware iwlwifi-7265D-22.ucode
[24227.638660] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 22.391740.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[24227.685858] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 3165, REV=0x210
```

and `ifconfig -a` or NetworkManager (if you have it installed ofc) should show up your Wi-Fi interface.

Enjoy!

Comment: On **https://github.com/OpenELEC/iwlwifi-firmware.git**, you can find the firmware **iwlwifi-8000C-22.ucode** which doesn't answer to the question ..

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't answer to the question since this step actually helped me to get it working. It is not an answer for you, certainly.

Comment: It answers the question partially. 8000C-22 is just the older version of the firmware, so go ahead and use it if nothing else is available. But it would be really nice to have the newest version available for sure.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue, you can find the firmware here

https://github.com/OpenELEC/iwlwifi-firmware/blob/master/firmware/iwlwifi-8000C-19.ucode

Copy the file to /lib/firmware

Comment: Did anybody find 8000c-26 anywhere? I'm still having problems and the missing file does not seem to exist, I could not find it on Intel's download pages. Is this a bug in the iwlwifi module or do they simply not care?

Comment: unfortunately a broken link

Comment: You can find 13-22 and 27,31 on this page https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/iwlwifi/linux-firmware.git/plain/